# Jump out in Tkinter loop

Tags: python, user-interface, loops, tkinter, ttk

I am working on a Tkinter doesn't jump out problem.

There is what I am running:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

def plus(*args):
    value = float(a.get())
    value1 = float(b.get())
    result.set(value + value1)
    print "the result is " + str(result.get())

root = Tk()
root.title("Plus them")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="10 10 10 10")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

a = StringVar()
b = StringVar()
result = StringVar()

feet_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=a)
feet_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

feet_entry1 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=b)
feet_entry1.grid(column=5, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="the result is").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable = result).grid(column=5, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Plus", command=plus).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
    feet_entry.focus()
    root.bind('<Return>', plus)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image]

When it runs, it seems fine. But it doesn’t “jump out” no matter how many times I click the “Plus”, until I input new values for calculation and it still waiting for new entry.

How can I adjust to have it calculate only for once? Thanks.

Comment: Dont understand what you want to achieve. What is the purpose of this for loop `for child in mainframe.winfo_children()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your window execute only once and have plus button closing the window do as follow:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk




def plus(*args):
    value = float(a.get())
    value1 = float(b.get())
    result.set(value + value1)
    print "the result is " + str(result.get())
    root.destroy()             ####### look here !!!#######

root = Tk()

root.title("Plus them")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="10 10 10 10")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

a = StringVar()
b = StringVar()
result = StringVar()

feet_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=a)
feet_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

feet_entry1 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=b)
feet_entry1.grid(column=5, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="the result is").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable = result).grid(column=5, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Plus", command=plus).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)


# for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
#     child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

feet_entry.focus()
root.bind('<Return>', plus)

root.mainloop()
```

So here, in your plus callbeck you need to call `root.destroy()`. Also this loop `for child in mainframe.winfo_children()` does not make sense in my option, and its not needed. So I removed it in the example.

Comment: marvelous! thanks. and what if I want to keep the GUI running/open after execute the script, instead of closing it once run? I mean I can use the same small window for different calculations and no need to open it each time. is it possible?

Comment: You cant. `root.mainloop()` is an infinite loop. And until you close it, nothing past the `root.mainloop()` is going to be executed. However, if you want to keep your window open, and calculate many sums, just comment out `root.destroy()` in the plus callback.

Comment: thanks again. by the way, I dream to make a small program so likely I need to package above to an .exe file? Could you please point me the direction as well? many thanks.

Comment: Cant help with exe unfortunately. I work on Linux, and no exe files there. Have not much experience with python on windows :-(